# How should I get last login timestamp of Azure AD B2C user?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I need to get below details of Azure AD B2C users -

- Created Date user account
- Last Login
- User is Active or De-active

I have explored Azure AD graph API (Get-User) but it throws some exception.
https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Still I am not sure that, above information will get from Azure AD B2C graph API or not.

Is there any other way to get the above Azure AD B2C user details?

Comment: Now we have 2020. Still not possible to get this info?

Answer (score 0):

The below API will provide the response

'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$select=displayName,signInActivity

```
              {
                  "displayName":  "test",
                  "id":  "bf7a60-3db4-4943-8d45-a7de9276c"
              },
              {
                  "displayName":  "Admin",
                  "id":  "ae1f1dd6-886a-484b-b46e-e48cce4",
                  "signInActivity":  "@{lastSignInDateTime=2021-03-15T14:06:21Z; lastSignInRequestId=55909a8c-2c13-4e5a-8e23-8952571a0300}"
              },
```

Comment: But there is no signInActivity property.